# Python script freezes until switching back to the interpreter

Tags: python

this is the first time I have encountered this problem. I have experienced a "while True" loop exiting unreasonably before but it never caused any issues. My code is a bot for gimkit if anyone knows it. It takes a screenshot of the question and tries to quess the answer. If it quesses correctly it will save the answer and use it when the question shows up again.

```
import pyautogui
import win32con, win32api
import keyboard
import time
import PIL

#(3, 382)
#(1364, 722)

#(0, 193)
#(1363, 374)

"""
(10, 386, 660, 150)
(163, 26, 47)

(691, 388, 660, 150)
(213, 117, 27)

(9, 562, 660, 150)
(19, 152, 73)

(691, 562, 660, 150)
(9, 130, 199)
"""


def click(coord):
    win32api.SetCursorPos(coord)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0)
    time.sleep(0.08)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0)
    time.sleep(0.8)

optionsRange = [(10, 386, 660, 150), (691, 388, 660, 150), (9, 562, 660, 150), (691, 562, 660, 150)]
questions = []
tries = []
optionsScreen = []
answers = []
options = [(320, 450), (1030, 450), (320, 640), (1030, 640)]
end = False
pause = False

keyboard.wait('g')
print('started!')
while not end:
    while pause:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('p'):
            pause = False
            break
        elif keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
            end = True
            break
    if end:
        break
    time.sleep(1)

    
    while not pause:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        im = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(0,193, 1363, 181))
        pixels = []
        #-------------------freeze-here---------------
                        
        if im in questions:
            #-------------------freeze-here---------------
            index = questions.index(im)
            answer = answers[index]            
            
            if answer != None:
                #-------------------freeze-here---------------
                for i in range(4):
                    option = pyautogui.screenshot(region = optionsRange[i])
                    pixels = option.load()
                    for x in range(option.size[0]):
                        for y in range(option.size[1]):
                            if pixels[x, y][0] != 255:
                                pixels[x, y] = (0, 0, 0)
                    if pixels == answer:                    
                        click(options[i])
                        time.sleep(0.4)
                        if pyautogui.pixel(5, 200)[0] == 183:
                            print("something's not right")
                        break
                        
                
            else:
                for i in range(4):
                    tried = tries[index]
                    option = pyautogui.screenshot(region = optionsRange[i])
                    pixels = option.load()
                    for x in range(option.size[0]):
                        for y in range(option.size[1]):
                            if pixels[x, y][0] != 255:
                                pixels[x, y] = (0, 0, 0)
                    if pixels in tried:
                       continue
                    else:
                        click(options[i])
                        time.sleep(0.4)
                        
                        if pyautogui.pixel(5, 200)[0] == 183:
                            tries[index].append(pixels)
                            
                        else:
                            answers[index] = pixels
                    click((680, 650))
        else:
            questions.append(im)
            option = pyautogui.screenshot(region = optionsRange[0])
            click(options[0])
            time.sleep(0.4)

            pixels = option.load()
            for x in range(option.size[0]):
                for y in range(option.size[1]):
                    if pixels[x, y][0] != 255:
                        pixels[x, y] = (0, 0, 0)
            
            if pyautogui.pixel(5, 200)[0] == 183:
                tries.append([pixels])
                answers.append(None)
                
            else:           
                answers.append(pixels)
                tries.append(None)
            click((680, 650))
                
        if keyboard.is_pressed('p'):
            pause = True
            time.sleep(5)
```

But when testing the bot out it seems to be doing well but then it just stops. I check if it caught an exception but that's not the case and it starts working again. I tried it a second time but this time I wait for like 2 minutes before alt-tabing to the interpreter but just as I do that it resumes the code.

Is this a known issue or is it something with my code? I think the thread is getting paused but I have no idea how to prevent that.

I'm using Python 3.7.0

EDIT: added freeze points

Comment: Any way you can pare that down to a **minimal** [mre]? When you instrument it with *prints* or logging where exactly does it stop? Is it the same place every time? When you inspect the  daa at the point that it stops is there anything funny about it? Why doyou think the thread is *getting paused*?

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables - it is called `"print debuging"`. Maybe it have wrong values in variables or it execute different code then you expect. I don't know if you can prevent to stop threads - they are controled by system (Windows/Linux/MacOS). Python has `GIL` which blocks threads and it executes only one thread at the time.

Comment: @wwii I have edited in places where last debug-print(s) were called before freezing. I will try to slim the code down next.

Comment: also I don't think it's something to do with my code because I literaly just have to switch back to the interpreter to resume it. Nothing in my code uses "tab" or "alt" and I can use my mouse to switch and get the same result anyways.